# Join in Hibernate Query

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have classes:

```
class User{
String id;
ArrayList<UserAttribute> attributeList=new ArrayList<UserAttribute>();
}

class UserAttribute{
User user;
String value;
String key;
}
```

I have tables associated to classes.

**table** user

```
column id
```

**table** user_attribute

```
column user_id
column key
column value
```

**example user table content**

```
user_id="123"

user_id="234"
```

**example user_attribute table contents**

```
user_id="123", key="address", value="green house street"

user_id=234, key="address", value="blue house street"

user_id="123", key="phone", value="234324"

user_id="234", key="phone", value="786988"
```

I want to get the user who has address "green house street" **and**(not or) has phone "234324"

I write sql(oracle) in sql editor:

```
 select u.* from user u left join user_attribute prop on u.id=prop.user_id inner join user_attribute prop2 on prop.user_id = prop2.user_id where prop.value = 'green house street' and prop.key = 'address' and prop2.key ='phone'  and prop2.value = '234324';
```

I tried many thing on hibernate side: but cannot use join because get

"unecpected token on"

error when using "on" clause.

in the end I wrote

```
entityManager.createQuery(
select u from User u, u.attributeList prop, u.attributeList prop2 where prop.value = :address and prop.key = :key and prop2.key =:key2  and prop2.value = :phone and prop.user.id=u.id and prop2.user.id=u.id and prop2.user.id=prop.user.id
)..setParameter("key", "address")
                .setParameter("phone", "234324")
                .setParameter("key2", "phone")
                .setParameter("address", "green house street").getSingleResult();
```

still no chance,

I try hard to find a single query solution but cannot achive so far.
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make two joins, but don't need to specify any `on` clause, since Hibernate knows, thanks to the mapping of the association, how the tables are linked together. So the following query should work:

```
select u from User u
inner join u.attributeList a1
inner join u.attributeList a2
where a1.value = 'green house street' and a1.key = 'address' 
and a2.key ='phone' and a2.value = '234324'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is having problem with "on" clause .

Use native sql query..

plz refer [HQL Problem](http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/hibernate)